# Slide down one at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I know there are multiple questions like this, but I think this is a bit unique... Here is what is my code first of..

```
<div class="holster_infobox_helper">

        <div id="infobox_holder">
            <div class="infobox">
                <h2><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/color_18/access_point.png">Alerts</h2>
                <p class="infobox_alert"><a href="<?php echo $ROOTPATH; ?>jobs"><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/gray_18/hammer.png">Accepted Proposal</a></p>
                  <p class="infobox_alert"><a href="<?php echo $ROOTPATH; ?>jobs"><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/gray_18/hammer.png">Accepted Proposal</a></p>
                    <p class="infobox_alert"><a href="<?php echo $ROOTPATH; ?>jobs"><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/gray_18/hammer.png">Accepted Proposal</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="infobox">
                <h2><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/color_18/hammer.png">Jobs</h2>
                <p class="infobox_alert"><a href="<?php echo $ROOTPATH; ?>jobs"><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/gray_18/hammer.png">Accepted Proposal</a></p>
                <p class="infobox_alert"><a href="<?php echo $ROOTPATH; ?>jobs"><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/gray_18/hammer.png">Accepted Proposal</a></p>
                  <p class="infobox_alert"><a href="<?php echo $ROOTPATH; ?>jobs"><img src="<?php $ROOTPATH ?>/img/icons/gray_18/hammer.png">Accepted Proposal</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I have a small snippet,

```
$(".infobox_alert").delay(2500).slideDown(1000);
```

That makes all of the .infobox_alert

's drop down at once. I'd like to have each one from each "infobox" drop down one by one. Starting from the first infobox, one two three, then the next infobox, one two three, then the next. So it opens one by one per box, then onto the next, one by one.

Comment: Try using the each method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @Leeish Thank you, but I am unsure how to open one at a time per box then move onto the next. Sorry

Comment: You can probably nuke the PHP clutter from your code sample - it doesn't seem like it's really important for the purposes of this question.

Comment: This is for illustrative purposes only. Not necessarily best way to write the script. http://jsfiddle.net/wyfB6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursivity:

```
slideIt(0);

function slideIt(i){
   var el =$(".infobox_alert:eq("+i+")");
   if(el == undefined) 
       return;
   el.slideDown(1000);
   setTimeout(function(){slideIt(++i)}, 1000);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Yjnny/

Comment: this is almost perfect! One modification.. One some of the boxes, they are sliding upwards instead of sliding down the from <h2> title in place. Is there a way to keep that from happening?

Comment: @greycode That's probably an unrelated problem. Isolate it and ask a new SO question.

Comment: @millimoose Thank you and thank you Cristy!!! I appreciate it guys.. this has been killing me!

Comment: What do you mean by sliding upwards? On the JSfiddle everything slides from top-to bottom under the h2.

Comment: @greycode Here's a variant on this answer that uses callback functions: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LekaB - it's substantially the same, but lets you specify the group of items to slide down naturally as a parameter instead of constructing selectors.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method, you can delay the amount of time the slidedown takes:

```
var i = 0;
$(".infobox_alert").each(function () {
  $(this).delay(1000*i).slideDown(1000);
  i++;
});
```

The nice thing about this apporach over chaining on the complete event is that you can stagger them out by adding to the delay or shorten the delay. If you shorten it, they come down in order, but don't wait until the previous one is completely done sliding to start their sliding.  Try playing with the delay until you get the desired effect.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MKKbj/

Comment: @JohnKoemer this is opening them all at the same time like the snippet I posted..

Comment: @JohnKoemer (as with the other answer) on some of the boxes, they are sliding upwards instead of sliding down the from <h2> title in place. Is there a way to keep that from happening? It happens on the second, fourth, and sixth box.

Comment: You can place the i in the function(i) and then there is no need to declare i nor iterate over it. I believe this variable wouldn't take less memory as well. http://jsfiddle.net/MKKbj/2/

Comment: @Christy's method is nice, but John Koerner's is the one I tend to fallback on because of the ability to set a delay before executing the .each() method. E.g. `$(".infobox_alert").delay(1500).each(...);` This is really handy when you want to delay the animation from executing on your page (or while other animations are finished running.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the callback of each slide down in a recursive function.

Create a function that slides down the next one:

```
var slideDownNext = function(element){
    element.next().slideDown( function(){ slideDownNext($(this)) } );
}
```

Then attach that to the first element:

```
$(".infobox_alert:first").slideDown( function(){ slideDownNext($(this)) } );
```

As mentioned in the other answers you could use a timeout/delay to stagger the sliding, but that is not going to guarantee that the next one doesn't open before the previous one has finished. Even if you set the time of the animation to be the same as the delay other things can happen that might make the next animation start before the previous one has finished.

**Update:**
I hadn't fully looked at the html in the question and assumed all elements were siblings. As that is not the case a solution like this should wok better:

```
var alerts = $('.infobox_alert')
function slideNext(i){
    alerts.eq(i).slideDown( function(){ slideNext(++i); } );
}
alerts.eq(0).slideDown( function(){ slideNext( ++i ); } );
```

Comment: this is working great! But it isn't doing all of the "infobox"'s.. It does the first one fine, but there are 6 total boxes with a few infobo_alerts inside each...

Comment: This code is just an example and would work if all the things you want to slide down were siblings in the html. To get it to work with your current html I'd recommend using a collection of all the alert elements and iterating over them recursively in the callbacks.